# NPE on my Android App for setOnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I'm trying to implement a ListView with an embedded Button. I've made my list item view separately and followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEEYYvVwJGY) tutorial.

When I try running it, I get an NPE on the button's setOnClickListener because it says it's a null reference. Kindly point out where I've gone wrong or if I need to do anything else.

Here's my code:

Main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Data">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="319dp"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="3"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter value"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
                android:onClick="bringList"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select reason:"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

List Item:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/listitem"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Info"
    android:id="@+id/listbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listitem"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.abhinav.data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Data extends ActionBarActivity {

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    makeList();
    lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list, data));
}

private void makeList() {
    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++) {
        data.add("Theorem"+i);
    }
}

public void bringList() {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_data, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private int listlayout;
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        listlayout = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vw = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(listlayout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
            viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //pop up dialog with theorem info
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button presss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            vw = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            vw.title.setText(getItem(position));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    Button button;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide some code and logcat output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this Lines

```
viewHolder.title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
viewHolder.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
```

to

```
viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem);
viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
```

NPE is because you reading view incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your List Item might only inflate the TextView element, because it's the actuall root element for the XML.

I recommend wrapping both the `TextView` and the `Button` in your `list.xml` file with a `LinearLayout` so the actual root view will wrap all your views.

Here's an example of what stacking both views vertically would look like with a LinearLayout for a ListView item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/listbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listitem"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the case, but you are creating two different ViewHolders. Use `vw = new ViewHolder();`
And maybe you need to use `convertView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);`